# “陈旧”这个词一定是贬义词吗?

Tags: meaning, word

> 陈旧：（形容词）旧；过时的

在复习、学习HSK7~9级词汇时，我遇到了“陈旧”这个词。我认为“陈旧”是贬义词，即陈旧的东西一定有什么缺点，比如它已经被淘汰掉了或者不再被人接受的，所以你不应该使用它，或者至少有着更好的选择。

我找到的例句包括这样的搭配：

> 陈旧的观念（或信念）
> 陈旧的设备
> 陈旧的信息
> 陈旧的词语

这些例子都和我的假设一致的：“陈旧”是贬义词。可是，我在[这里](https://youdao.com/result?word=lj%3A%E9%99%88%E6%97%A7&lang=en)也遇到了一些这类的句子：

> 这个人立刻意识到**这个托盘是陈旧而值钱**。
> 这家**陈旧的银行**外表虽不美丽，但内部非常漂亮。
> 州销售者从客户那里收取州销售税，并将其送到**陈旧的地方**。

在这些句子里，“陈旧”好像不是贬义词。与此同时，我不知道这些例句可不可靠，说不定这里的用法不准确。

**问题**：“陈旧”这个词一定是贬义词吗?

Answer (score 2):

陈旧 is not a negative word. It can be used to describe objective and abstract things. The core meaning is old, our-dated.

There is a similar word 陈腐, 陈腐 is negative， because 腐 means rotten, not usable.

Answer (score 1):

“陈旧” itself is not a derogatory term, it simply means "old" or "aged" But its extended meanings "outdated" or "obsolete" are terms for "criticizing" which is derogatory if the goal is to belittle someone

Examples:

- "陈旧" in "越**陈旧**的陈皮越值錢" (The **older** the tangerine peel, the more valuable it is) simply means "old" or "aged"
- "陈旧" in "**陈旧**的观念" literally means "old idea" but the actual meaning is "outdated" or "obsolete" (old idea --> outdated idea --> no longer valid -- go hide in a corner or something)

Conclusion

From the context, we can determine "陈旧" simply means "old" (neutral) or "outdated" (derogatory)

Example:

墨迹陈旧，非近代之物 (ink can't be outdated)

思想陈旧，不合時宜 (old thinking is generally outdated)

Answer (score 1):

陈 and 旧 were not derogatory in Old Chinese. But “陈旧” is a slightly derogatory to derogatory term in many modern Chinese usages.

The entry for “陈旧” in 《重編國語辭典修訂本》 says this:

> 陳舊：過時而不合時宜。（dated and antiquated）

> 思想陳舊的人，常被稱為今之古人。People with old-fashioned ideas are often referred to as the ancient people of today. *(derogatory)*

In 《现代汉语词典》 the entry for 陈旧 says this:

> 陈旧：旧的；过时的。（old; dated）

> 设备**虽然**有点儿陈旧，**但**还能使用。The equipment is a bit old, **but** still works. *(slightly derogatory)*

> 陈旧的观念应该被抛弃。Old-fashioned ideas should be discarded. *(derogatory)*

A random comment on an online bookstore says:

> 知识有些陈旧，**但是**书真的很好。 The knowledge is a bit outdated, **but** the book is really good. *(derogatory)*

There is a medical term called

> 陈旧性肺结核 Obsolete Tuberculosis. *(neutral)*

Other examples:

Derogatory:

(他)抱怨倫敦的地鐵非常陳舊。

看法总是要陈旧过时，而事实永远不会陈旧过时。

家俱陳設實在陳舊不堪。

她使用的詞語未免太陳舊了。

德国总理默克尔周三警告俄罗斯不要重新陷入关于势力范围的“陈旧思维模式”。

不落俗套，摆脱陈旧感！

言辞也许陈旧，情意不曾偏离。

两个州选区居民各自面对不同的民生问题，包括水灾、道路、沟渠、杂草、基建陈旧、牛只游荡等。

厂领导终于抛弃陈旧观念,开始引进新的生产技术。

宇宙和社会是那么陈旧，无味，虽则它们其实比‘儿时’新鲜得多了。

那新摆出来的烧饼，更是陈旧不堪，暗想这种烧饼，还有什么人要买呢。

这些规章既陈旧又不现实。

Neutral:

陳舊性瘀血

Hence it is derogatory **in most common usages**. There do exist a few exceptions, mostly academic terms.

Comment: Personally I prefer 老 instead of 陈旧 for 越"old"的陈皮越值錢. 陈旧 sounds a bit weird within the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are machine translated from English. Youdao's Chinese examples aren't reliable as it's facing Chinese users to learn English and crawled from web.